# os.path equivalent for web urls in python?

Tags: python, url, path

For joining, splitting and processing file and directory paths python's `os.path` modul is great. Is there an equivalent for web urls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**urlparse**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) - Parse URLs into components, is the module for you..

To actually fetch urls & data, you need [**urllib2**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html).

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help :

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html